# How to add category to column in Power BI?

Tags: matrix, powerbi, report, dashboard, slicers

I have data similar to this format:

```
customerName  |  Type of Sale  |  Sales Amount  |   Unit Purchased
-------------------------------------------------------------------
A             |   Online       |   1500         |    4
B             |   Offline      |   2000         |    5
C             |   Online       |   3000         |    4
D             |   Offline      |   4000         |    4
```

and I want data in following format in Power BI in Matrix Format

```
Metric          |  Sales Amount      | Units Purchased
-----------------------------------------------------------
 Customer Name  | Online | Offline   |   Online  | Offline
-----------------------------------------------------------
A               | 15000  |   0       |   4       |  0
B               |   0    |   2000    |   0       |  5
```

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this kind of visualization, but this needs some steps (more effort, Lower performance compared to the standard design.)

First we need an additional table with lables "Sales Amount" and "Units Purchased".
Relationship many to many.

[image]
[image]

Add additional measures:

```
Offline = 
var sale = CALCULATE(sum('Sales'[Sales Amount]), FILTER(ALL('Sales'[Type of Sale]), 'Sales'[Type of Sale] = "Offline"))
var purch = CALCULATE(sum('Sales'[Unit Purchased]), FILTER(ALL('Sales'[Type of Sale]), 'Sales'[Type of Sale] = "Offline"))
return
if (SELECTEDVALUE('Lables'[LableName]) = "Purchase",purch,sale)

Online = 
var sale = CALCULATE(sum('Sales'[Sales Amount]), FILTER(ALL('Sales'[Type of Sale]), 'Sales'[Type of Sale] = "Online"))
var purch = CALCULATE(sum('Sales'[Unit Purchased]), FILTER(ALL('Sales'[Type of Sale]), 'Sales'[Type of Sale] = "Online"))
return
if (SELECTEDVALUE('Lables'[LableName]) = "Sales Amount", sale,purch)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, But could you tell, why and How you created ToJoin column in Sales Table, is it calculate column or something else?

Comment: This is just new calculated column with one value = 1

Comment: Ok, thanks, How to remove blank values in the above matrix

Comment: What do you mean by saying "remove blank values"; if any of your measure return value then the whole row is visible. If you want 0 instead of BLANK then add additional IF statement in measure if( BLANK( <current calculation>), 0,  <current calculation>)