# How to replace a blank value with zero in Power BI matrix?

Tags: matrix, powerbi, report, dax, dashboard

I have a matrix in the below format, where Online and Offline are measures. I want to replace blank values for Online and Offline with zero. How can I do this?

[image: Sample Matrix]

Online measure DAX (similar for Offline measure)

```
Online = 
VAR sale = 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('Sales Data'[Sale Amount]), 
        FILTER(ALL('Sales Data'[Type of Sale]), 'Sales Data'[Type of Sale] = "Online")
    )

VAR purch = 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('Sales Data'[Units Purchased]), 
        FILTER(ALL('Sales Data'[Type of Sale]), 'Sales Data'[Type of Sale] = "Online")
    )

RETURN IF(SELECTEDVALUE(Labels[Metric]) = "Sales Amount", sale, purch)
```

Comment: Hello, would you mind adding the DAX code that you use for the measures to your question description? This will help us better solve this.

Comment: Online = 
var sale = CALCULATE(sum('Sales Data'[Sale Amount]), FILTER(ALL('Sales Data'[Type of Sale]), 'Sales Data'[Type of Sale] = "Online"))
var purch = CALCULATE(sum('Sales Data'[Units Purchased]), FILTER(ALL('Sales Data'[Type of Sale]), 'Sales Data'[Type of Sale] = "Online"))
return
if (SELECTEDVALUE(Labels[Metric]) = "Sales Amount", sale,purch)

Comment: @MattKocak, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71879175/how-to-add-category-to-column-in-power-bi/71881777?noredirect=1#comment127023235_71881777, this question, I am trying to solve, there seems some problem with my Dax Expression

Comment: Hey, did my post answer your question? If so, would you mind accepting and upvoting the solution?

Answer (score 0):

In your measures, you will want to specifically set any BLANK() results to 0. Then return those 0's instead of BLANK()'s. Below, I've modified the Online measure that you provided with this adjustment.

```
Online = 
VAR sale = 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('Sales Data'[Sale Amount]), 
        FILTER(ALL('Sales Data'[Type of Sale]), 'Sales Data'[Type of Sale] = "Online")
    )
    
VAR saleWithZero = IF(ISBLANK(sale), 0, sale)

VAR purch = 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('Sales Data'[Units Purchased]), 
        FILTER(ALL('Sales Data'[Type of Sale]), 'Sales Data'[Type of Sale] = "Online")
    )

VAR purchWithZero = IF(ISBLANK(purch), 0, purch)

RETURN IF(SELECTEDVALUE(Labels[Metric]) = "Sales Amount", saleWithZero, purchWithZero)
```

Below is a sample matrix that I tested this on.

[image: Sample Matrix]